# how to check is not null and greater than in android sqlite query

Tags: android

I am using db query, how to check one value is not null and greater than other value in a query.

```
db.query(DB_TAB, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, stemp, dtemp },stemp + "!=" + null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I want to check both stemp and dtemp is not null and also dtemp is greater than stemp.

Comment: during creation of DB only you can define column with not null so you need not require for checking it.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914860/sqlite-query-to-retrieve-all-rows-where-not-null-android

Answer (score 0):

Also, different in sqlite is "<>" not "!=".

Comment: ["The non-equals operator can be either != or <>."](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)